# How to capture packets of rysnc using tcpdump

Tags: linux, networking, unix, rsync, tcpdump

I am trying to do rysnc a 4G file to another directory and want to capture rsync packets using tcpdump. I tried listning to port 873 which is used for rsync but did not find anything captured. I checked the config file , it says rsync is using port 873 only. Am i missing anything here ? IS there any better approach to do that ?

```
tcpdump  -n -vv "port 873"
tcpdump: WARNING: eth0: no IPv4 address assigned
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 96 bytes

0 packets captured
0 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Comment: You are trying to listen on an interface with.. **no IPv4 address assigned**. With tcpdump you must specify explicitly the interface thru which data are flowing (hence said interface **must** have an IP address). In your case, that interface  is most likely your wifi interface.